# How can I speed up the program execution?

Tags: c++

I have a program that reads data from a file (a matrix of 400,000 * 3 elements) and writes it to a two-dimensional array and write this array. However, there is a problem: it all takes a long time (6 seconds). According to the conditions of correct tests, this should take no more than 2 seconds.

```
int main() 
{
    ifstream file_for_reading("C:\\Tests\\20");
    int a,b,c;
    int edge, number_of_vertexes;
    file_for_reading >> number_of_vertexes >> edge;
    if (number_of_vertexes < 1 || number_of_vertexes > 30000 || edge < 0 || edge>400000) { cout << "Correct your vallues"; exit(1); };
    short** matrix = new short* [edge];
    for (int i = 0; i < edge; i++)
        matrix[i] = new short[3];
    int tmp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < edge; i++) {
        file_for_reading >> matrix[i][tmp] >> matrix[i][tmp+1] >> matrix[i][tmp+2];
        tmp = 0;
    }
    file_for_reading.close();
    //Dijkstra(matrix, number_of_vertexes);
}
```

Comment: You may speed up the program execution, if you replace `short** matrix` with a flat array`short** matrix` and access elements `matrix[i][tmp]` using `matrix[i * edge + tmp]`.

Comment: This program will almost certainly be I/O bound, focus on that.

Comment: You may want to post to [codereview.se].

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead of allocating dynamically.  There is a constructor that tells the vector the size you want.

Comment: I recommend profiling, if possible (some profiling only goes down to the function level, not the statement).  Looks like file I/O is your bottleneck.  If you want to speed up the file I/O, read into a large buffer, then extract your data from the buffer.  The other bottleneck is converting from textual (human readable) format to native computer format.  In other words, "1234" to number 1234.  Lastly, one of your remaining bottlenecks would be cache "misses" and reloads.  This will happen when storing non-sequential data, such as `m[2][3][4]`.  then `m[2][4][4]`.

Comment: I forgot one of the obligatory efficiency questions:  What are your compiler optimization settings?  Are you measuring a release build or a debug build?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I'm sure that the problem is in the place where the file is written to the array.Optimization settings - installed Visual Studio and that's it. I'm a student newbie)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews 
I measure the time after which the first numbers appear in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S.M.'s advice is promising - just `short* matrix = new short [edge * 3];` then `for (int i = 0; i < edge * 3; i++) file_for_reading >> matrix[i];` to read the file.  Crucially, this puts all the file content into contiguous memory, which is more CPU cache friendly.

Using the following code I generated test input and measured the performance of your original approach and the contiguous-memory approach:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

using namespace std::literals;

#define ASSERT(X) \
    do { \
        if (X) break; \
        std::cerr << ':' << __LINE__ << " ASSERT " << #X << '\n'; \
        exit(1); \
    } while (false)

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    // for (int i = 0; i < 400000 * 3; ++i)
    //    std::cout << rand() % 32768 << ' ';

    // old way...
    std::ifstream in{"fasterread.in"};
    ASSERT(in);
    if (argc == 2 && argv[1] == "orig"s) {
        short** m = new short*[400000];
        for (int i = 0; i < 400000; ++i)
            m[i] = new short[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 400000; ++i)
            in >> m[i][0] >> m[i][1] >> m[i][2];
    }

    if (argc == 2 && argv[1] == "contig"s) {
        short* m = new short[400000 * 3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 400000 * 3; ++i)
            in >> m[i];
    }
}
```

I then compiled them with optimisations using GCC on Linux:

```
g++ -O2 -Wall -std=c++20 fasterread.cc -o fasterread
```

And ran them with the `time` utility to show elapsed time:

```
time ./fasterread orig; time ./fasterread contig
```

Over a dozen runs of each, the fastest the orig version completed was 0.063 seconds (I have a *fast* SSD), whilst contig took as little as 0.058 seconds.  Still not fast enough to meet your 3-fold reduction target.

That said, C++ `ifstream` supports locale translations whilst parsing numbers - using a slowish virtual dispatch mechanism - so may be slower than other text-to-number parsing that you could use or write.

But, when you're 100x slower than me - it's obviously your old HDD that sucks, and not the software parsing the numbers....

FWIW, I tried C-style I/O using [`fscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) and it proved slower for me - 0.077s.

Comment: Maybe I just misunderstand the time frame? I was just counting the time it would take for the numbers to appear on the console.

Comment: @Eugenos_Programos: maybe - if you're using Visual Studio, it could be quite slow at starting the program and displaying the output.  You could go to a command window, find the binary Visual Studio built, and run it from there to see how long it takes to complete the read.

Comment: The only problem is that I have 512 GB Ssd.  And in general, my laptop cannot be called old.

Comment: Can u explane me what mean  `#define ASSERT(X)`

Comment: You're taking 100x longer than my computer, despite having an SSD?  Something seriously wrong there.  (My SSD's a Gigabyte Aorus with read speed of 5000MB/s).    Re `ASSERT`, it lets me check something and have the program terminate with an error message if it's not true.  For example, `ASSERT(in);` checks that the `ifstream` object is in a good state, which will be true if the input file was opened successfully.  You could also use `ASSERT(in >> m[i][0] >> m[i][1] >> m[i][2]);` to check that the input operations worked.  They would not work if you reached EOF early or encountered a letter.

Comment: Is optimization using GCC so much affected?

Comment: @Eugenos_Programos: not for me - for this, unoptimised vs. optimised doesn't make a noticable difference to the times I see, suggesting the disk and memory access delays dominate....

Comment: What do you print after this command?`time ./fasterread orig; time ./fasterread contig`

Comment: I also wanted to ask if you had a slight delay after entering the command in the console?

Comment: @Eugenos_Programos: the `time` commands print out the time taken to run the program - e.g. `./fasterread orig  0.06s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 0.062 total
./fasterread contig  0.05s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 0.053 total` - the last number is the one that matters most, but it includes program start up time.  It all happens so fast on my computer - the output's there almost immediately.  Windows may or may not have a similar `time` program - I don't remember - but even if it does the format might differ a little, not that that would matter.

Comment: I print this command and this is a result:
`real    0m8,421s
user    0m0,000s
sys     0m0,031s`

Which of them is what we are talking about?

Comment: "real" should be the total wall-clock time the program took to run, whereas "user" should be the amount of CPU time the process spent in unprivileged user mode, which is the mode it will be in when parsing the numbers and storing them into the array - obviously that number can't be 0, so - surprise, surprise, Windows - it looks like the tools themselves suck.  "sys" is time in which the Operating System is in privileged mode doing things like disk reads.  That user + sys doesn't even approach real suggests your laptop may not have had enough cores & memory to dedicate to your process.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an optimized version for you:

```
const int limit = edge / 2;  
for (int i = 0; i < limit; i += 2)
{
    /* register */ int a, b, c, d, e, f;
    file_for_reading >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e >> f;
    matrix[i][0] = a;
    matrix[i][1] = b;
    matrix[i][2] = c;
    matrix[i + 1][0] = d;
    matrix[i + 1][1] = e;
    matrix[i + 1][2] = f;
}
for (; i < edge; ++i)
{
    /* register */ int a, b, c;
    file_for_reading >> a >> b >> c;
    matrix[i][0] = a;
    matrix[i][1] = b;
    matrix[i][2] = c;
}
```

Here are the optimization principles, I'm trying to achieve in the above example:

1. Keep the file streaming (more), read more data per transaction.
2. Group the matrix assignments together, separate from the input.
   This allows the compiler and processor to optimize.  The processor can reduce memory fetches to take advantage of prefetching.
3. Hopefully, the compiler can use registers for the local variables.  Register access is faster than memory access.
4. By grouping the assignments, maybe the compiler can use some advanced processor instructions.
5. Loop unrolling.  The loop overhead (comparison and increment) are performed less often.

The best idea is to set your compiler for highest optimization and create a release build.  Also have your compiler print the assembly language for the functions.  The compiler may already perform some of the above optimizations.  IMHO, it never hurts to make your code easier for the compiler to optimize. :-)

**Edit 1:**
I'm hoping also that the matrix assignment may occur while reading in the "next" group of variables.  This would be a great optimization.  I'm open to people suggesting edits to this answer showing how to do that (without using threads).

Comment: The `/* register */` comment is a indication to the *reader* that the variables should be placed into registers.  The compiler may or may not use registers here.

Comment: The OP will get more performance out of the above code by allocating the matrix as a flat array (not an array of pointers).